# Update IIS binding in configuration file, not GUI

Tags: iis, iis-7

Can I update IIS binding in configuration file? I have six servers, needing to sync bindings among them.

Do you have any idea to facilitate my task? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You sure can use Bindings/Binding element in the web server's ApplicationHost.config (not Web.Config) to setup multiple bindings directly similar to as below however be sure to keep the setting site specific so bindings reflect correct setting to specific site:

```
<site name="Contoso" id="2">
  <application path="/" applicationPool="Contoso">
     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="192.168.0.1:443:www.contoso.com" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:" />
  </bindings>
</site>
```

More info:
http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/site/bindings/binding

Comment: For bindings specify with GUI and web.config, what is higher priority?

Comment: I think is the convenience and environment which will decided what you will choose. While a GUI will help you to do simpler task but if you have to repeat the same task again and again, its best to done in configuration as doing in GUI, it actually updating the configuration underneath. Also when the IIS starts all the website configured in it, each web site is starts using its configuration so  GUI and configuration are two separate context. Some configuration can be changed at runtime with GUI but you may not have access to GUI in some cases.